# How can I solve error in Jupyter notebook?

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook

Now I use jupyter notebook in my desktop PC.
Jupyter notebook stop after running a file a few days ago,
but I didn't found exact cause.

I saw this error message from jupyter notebook.
" File failed to load: http://localhost:8888/static/components/MathJax/extensions/Safe.js "

How can I solve this problem?

Answer (score 3):

Refer to this thread [on GitHub](https://github.com/jupyter/jupyter/issues/227)

This might be caused by a large output.

You need to install **nbstripout** and then use **nbstripout YOURFILE.ipynb** in terminal to get rid of the large output.